# Go, Press return to continue

Tags: go

I have a program that is taking an array and shuffling it, once it has done this it will print out one of the first value from the shuffled array. Once it prints out the value I want to it display a 'Press return to continue' message will be displayed. This message will presist until the user presses return, then it will get the next value from the shuffled array.

I have a script working fine for the first value but after I press return it just creates empty lines in my terminal.

Here is my example:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    users := make(map[int]string)

    users[0] = "Mike"
    users[1] = "Paul"
    users[2] = "Steve"
    users[3] = "Lawrence"
    users[4] = "Stephen"
    users[5] = "James"

    getNextSpeaker(users)

}

func getNextSpeaker(users map[int]string) {
    numUsers := len(users)
    list := randList(1, numUsers)

    for _, element := range list {
        fmt.Println(users[element-1])
        pressAnyKey()
    }

}

func randList(min, max int) []int {
    if max < min {
        min, max = max, min
    }
    length := max - min + 1
    t0 := time.Now()
    rand.Seed(int64(t0.Nanosecond()))
    list := rand.Perm(length)
    for index, _ := range list {
        list[index] += min
    }

    return list
}

func pressAnyKey() string {
    fmt.Println("Press Return To Continue...")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input, err := reader.ReadString('.')
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return input
}
```

Terminal Output:

```
$ go run src/RandomMeetingSpeaker/meeting.go
Paul
Press Return To Continue...
<empty line...>
<empty line...>
<empty line...>
<empty line...>
<empty line...>
etc etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReadString` takes the delimiter byte. In your case, that's a newline, not a dot. Simply replace the line

```
input, err := reader.ReadString('.')
```

with

```
input, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
```

and [it will work](http://ideone.com/qv6tb8#stdout).